# recv - When does it start to discard unprocessed packets?

Tags: sockets, recv

We are using [recv(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) in order to listen to incoming ICMP packets in a network management application in which there is a status poll feature to ping all managed hosts.

In a productive environment, the number of managed hosts can become pretty large (1,000+), and at the moment, when said status poll is performed, we send out all the ping requests sequentially with no delay inbetween.

Obviously, this will lead to many ping replies being sent back almost simultaneously, and it appears that our dispatching routine cannot catch up. This seems to cause that packets are dropped and the ping replies are never actually received by our application. We believe so because many hosts are falsely detected as being "unavailable".

The dispatcher doesn't do anything more than adding incoming replies to an "inbox" of sorts, which is processed later by another thread, ie it does not take much time and can probably not be optimized any further.

Is it possible that the internal packet buffer used by recv (in the kernel? in the network hardware?) fills up and starts dropping packets? If so, is there a good way to determine a reasonable maximum amount of simultaneous pings that can be performed safely (ie by getting that buffer size from the OS)?

Comment: Can you show some code ? How are you listening for ICMP datagrams ?

Comment: `int read = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);` - it's as simple as that. After that, the packet is analyzed for an ICMP header etc. The buffer is somewhat over a kilobyte, but IIRC that has nothing to do with packets that lie on the socket's stack. Besides, we are not interested in the ICMP data, so it's no problem if larger ICMP packets get truncated; we only need the header. The socket is a raw ICMP socket (created using `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);`), it is bound to `INADDR_ANY` and works correctly, it's just that some packets seem to get dropped when many replies are due.

Comment: Did you try tweaking `rmem_max` ?

Comment: Nope. First off, the application usually runs on Windows systems and I'm not sure if that kernel parameter even exists on Windows. Secondly, we can't tell customers to tamper with system settings like that just because our application isn't able to define a proper maximum amount of simultaneous pings... however, your reply implies that there _is_ indeed a limit and that's defined by `rmem_max`. Am I correct when I assume that if more data that `rmem_max` comes in and isn't processed quickly enough, old data will be discarded? Because that was my question really.